# How to populate a dropdown from a database and update the page when it's chosen?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf, html-select, h2

I'm making a website which will be a bit of a mock Pokédex as it where, and I'm trying to get it so that there is a single page for a Pokémon, which will update based of a dropdown of possible Pokémon, which when clicked on will update the page with whichever Pokémon was selected.

The current issue I'm facing is that, despite there being a number of Pokémon in the database, the drop down doesn't appear, suggesting it's not picking up the correct values, or that it is, but it can't interpret the results properly.

The html with the dropdown is:

```html
<section class="dropdown">
            <form action="/pokemon" method="post" th:object="${pokemon}">
                <select th:each="pokemon : ${pokemonList}">
                    <option th:value="${pokemon.dexNum}" th:text="${pokemon.name}"></option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </section>
```

Which *should* be requesting this method on selection, I can't confirm how this works without the dropdown though, so it may be flawed.

```java
private EntityManager em = new EntityManager();

@PostMapping(value = "/pokemon")
    public Pokemon changeCurrentPokemon(int num) {
        pokemonService.setCurrentPokemon(em.find(Pokemon.class, num));
        return pokemonService.getCurrentPokemon();
    }
```

With the variables being accessed through:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/pokemon")
    public ModelAndView showPokemon() {

        return new ModelAndView("pokemon", "pokemon",
                pokemonService.getCurrentPokemon() != null
                        ? pokemonService.getCurrentPokemon()
                        : new Pokemon(1, "Bulbasaur", "Seed Pokemon", "/images/pokemon/1-Bulbasaur.png", "Grass", "Poison")
        );
    }
```

The pokemonService class is an implementation of pokemonService shown here:

```
package pokedex.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import pokedex.dao.PokemonRepository;
import pokedex.entities.Pokemon;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class PokemonServiceImpl implements PokemonService {

    private PokemonRepository pokemonRepository;
    private Pokemon currentPokemon;

    public PokemonServiceImpl(PokemonRepository pokemonRepository) {
        this.pokemonRepository = pokemonRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Pokemon> getPokemonList() {
        return pokemonRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void addPokemon(Pokemon pokemon) {
        currentPokemon = pokemon;
        pokemonRepository.save(pokemon);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentPokemon(Pokemon pokemon) {
        currentPokemon = pokemon;
    }

    @Override
    public Pokemon getCurrentPokemon() {
        return currentPokemon;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumberOfPokemon() {
        return (int) pokemonRepository.count();
    }
}
```

If anyone has any tips on how to get the forms done I would greatly appreciate the help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have a `pokemon` model variable and a `pokemon` variable in `th:each`. Change one of them. Also `pokemonList` is not set. Isn't it just a typo?

```
<section class="dropdown">
            <form action="/pokemon" method="post" th:object="${pokemon}">
                <select th:each="pokemon: ${pokemonList}">
                    <option th:value="${pokemon.dexNum}" th:text="${pokemon.name}"></option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </section>
```